# Recovering Corrupted Partition Table on Time Machine HD

Tags: hard-drive, backup, partition

I had a loss of power while I was restoring some data from a Time Machine backup. When I brought the computer back up, my 4TB drive was unusable, with OS X prompting me with a dialog that stated 'The disk you inserted was not readable by this computer.'

After a bunch of reading and digging around, I discovered that the issue was with the partition table. And indeed, when I try to look at it I see:

```
# sudo gpt -r -vv show disk2
gpt show: disk2: mediasize=4000787029504; sectorsize=512; blocks=7814037167
gpt show: disk2: PMBR at sector 0
gpt show: disk2: Bad CRC in GPT table at sector 2
gpt show: disk2: Bad CRC in GPT table at sector 7814037134
   start        size  index  contents
       0           1         PMBR
       1  7814037166
```

There are several similar issues here on stack exchange, and the solution is generally to rebuild the GPT manually, which all seems straight-forward enough. Luckily, I have access to an identical hd that's used as a Time Machine disk, and here's what I see with that one:

```
     start        size  index  contents
         0           1         PMBR
         1           1         Pri GPT header
         2          32         Pri GPT table
        34           6         
        40      409600      1  GPT part - "EFI System Partition"
    409640  7813365344      2  GPT part - ""
7813774984      262150         
7814037134          32         Sec GPT table
7814037166           1         Sec GPT header
```

Given that, it seems that recreating the GPT should be easy. However, as soon as I add the main backup partition, I immediately get that same 'The disk you inserted was not readable' dialog and if I print out the GPT, I get the exact same results as I started with -- as if I had never done any work on it.

So, start I'll start by creating the GPT structure and EFI partition:

```
# sudo gpt create -f disk2
# sudo gpt add -b 40 -i 1 -s 409600 -t C12A7328-F81F-11D2-BA4B-00A0C93EC93B disk2
disk2s1 added
# sudo gpt -r -vv show disk2
gpt show: disk2: mediasize=4000787029504; sectorsize=512; blocks=7814037167
gpt show: disk2: PMBR at sector 0
gpt show: disk2: Pri GPT at sector 1
gpt show: disk2: Sec GPT at sector 7814037166
     start        size  index  contents
         0           1         PMBR
         1           1         Pri GPT header
         2          32         Pri GPT table
        34           6
        40      409600      1  GPT part - C12A7328-F81F-11D2-BA4B-00A0C93EC93B
    409640  7813627494
7814037134          32         Sec GPT table
7814037166           1         Sec GPT header
```

Looks good so far. Now I create the second partition:

```
# sudo gpt add -b 409640 -i 2 -s 7813365344 -t 48465300-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC disk2
disk2s2 added
# sudo gpt -r -vv show disk2
gpt show: disk2: mediasize=4000787029504; sectorsize=512; blocks=7814037167
gpt show: disk2: PMBR at sector 0
gpt show: disk2: Bad CRC in GPT table at sector 2
gpt show: disk2: Bad CRC in GPT table at sector 7814037134
   start        size  index  contents
       0           1         PMBR
       1  7814037166
```

And now I'm back where I started. Is there something I'm missing? Anyone have something else I can try?

Thanks.

Edit: Note that if I use gdisk to make that second partition a smaller than the total it should be (say, 1TB instead of taking up the rest of the disk), I don't see that error message and the GPT doesn't get magically reset.

```
# sudo gpt -r -vv show -l disk2
gpt show: disk2: mediasize=4000787029504; sectorsize=512; blocks=7814037167
gpt show: disk2: PMBR at sector 0
gpt show: disk2: Pri GPT at sector 1
gpt show: disk2: Sec GPT at sector 7814037166
     start        size  index  contents
         0           1         PMBR
         1           1         Pri GPT header
         2          32         Pri GPT table
        34           6
        40      409600      1  GPT part - "EFI System Partition"
    409640  2147483648      2  GPT part - "Backup"
2147893288  5666143846
7814037134          32         Sec GPT table
7814037166           1         Sec GPT header
```

It won't mount at this point, and running fsck_hfs tells me that there are an invalid number of allocation blocks, but at least it doesn't automatically get trashed. Is this indicative that my problem is that I'm setting the bounds of that second partition incorrectly?

Comment: Try to destroy the gpt: `sudo gpt destroy diskX`. Then try to repeat your steps to create a new GUIDpt and add the two partitions. If this fails, zero the first 34 and last 33 blocks: `sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/diskX count=34 bs=512` and `sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/diskX seek=7814037134 count=33 bs=512`. Use the proper diskX here. Then repeat the 3 steps to rebuild the GUIDpt once more. diskX mustn't be mounted.